# Makefile rebuild the whole project

Tags: makefile

I have this `Makefile` , everytime i `make` into the console it rebuild the whole project i know it is  some sort of `.PHONY` mistake but i can't figure it out.

Here is the `Makefile` :

```
all: start run

run: prog.o move prog

prog:   prog.o
        gcc object/prog.o -o exec/prog  


prog.o: src/prog.c src/prog.h
        gcc -c src/prog.c

move:
        mv *.o object

start:
        mkdir -p exec object

clean: 
        rm -rf object exec

.PHONY:  start clean move run
```

I know there is similar topics but i can't see where is my mistake.

Comment: Prerequisites do not by default run in sequence. You probably want to avoid `mv` in your Makefile to avoid this sort of issue.

Answer (score 0):

Both `prog.o` and `prog` do not exist in the current directory (and all other targets are phony). So what do you expect? Effectively, all your targets must be rebuilt every time.

```
PROG = exec/prog
OBJ = object/prog.o
SRC = src/prog.c src/prog.h

all: $(PROG)

$(PROG): $(OBJ) | exec
    gcc $^ -o $@

$(OBJ): $(SRC) | object
    gcc -c $< -o $@

exec object:
    mkdir -p $@

clean: 
    rm -rf exec object

.PHONY: all clean
```

Comment: Is it normal that it show `Makefile:8: *** missing separator.  Stop.` when there is no space at that line.

Comment: @Haskell-newb "Missing separator" is usually because of using spaces instead of tabs.

Comment: Yeah i know i literally remade your file with tabs and still get the same error.

Comment: @Haskell-newb Check your editor settings etc. It should work.